# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)

Tags: python, django

I've searched through similar questions, but nothing seems relevant to my situation.

Why does this code work fine:

```
<form action="/signup/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
[FORM]
</form>
```

but

```
<form id="signup-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
[FORM]
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".submit-signup").on("click", function() {
    var user = $("#signup_form").serialize();
    console.log(user);
    $.post("/signup/", user, function() {
    });
});
});
 </script>
```

not work?

Here is signup in views.py:

```
@requires_csrf_token
def signup(request):
[STUFF]

return render(request, 'signup.html', {[STUFF}})
```

What else can I provide that would help? Basically I am trying to take a page and turn it into a modal that does the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: That counts as AJAX POST call https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing an ajax post call for which you need to give csrf token also:

```
$.post("/signup/", {
    user: user, 
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
}, function() {
   // success todo
}, function(){
   // fail todo
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm getting "unexpected token :" at the csrfmiddlewaretoken line, and nothing else works yet, but I got the initial error to go away :)

Comment: @ballardjw2 can you paste the exact error message please?

Comment: " (index):319 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " Line 319 is the csrfmiddlewaretoken line.